# Doesn't get the output in Java Database Connectivity

Tags: eclipse, jdbc

I'm working on Java Database Connectivity through Eclipse IDE. I built a database through Ubuntu Terminal, and I need to connect and work with it. However, when I just add "mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar" to the project library, I don't get the project output, but the following output is showed, anybody knows what this is and how I can get the output from my project ?

```
    <ConnectionProperties>
 <PropertyCategory name="Connection/Authentication">
  <Property name="user" required="No" default="" sortOrder="-2147483647" since="all">
    The user to connect as
  </Property>
  <Property name="password" required="No" default="" sortOrder="-2147483646" since="all">
    The password to use when connecting
  </Property>
  <Property name="socketFactory" required="No" default="com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory" sortOrder="4" since="3.0.3">
    The name of the class that the driver should use for creating socket connections to the server. This class must implement the interface 'com.mysql.jdbc.SocketFactory' and have public no-args constructor.
  </Property>
  <Property name="connectTimeout" required="No" default="0" sortOrder="9" since="3.0.1">
    Timeout for socket connect (in milliseconds), with 0 being no timeout. Only works on JDK-1.4 or newer. Defaults to '0'.
  </Property>
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Run your java file which tries to connect to MySQL through JDBC as a Application.

1)Right Click on java file

2)Go on run as

3) select java application.

It solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the process for installing the driver. You only need to follow these steps
once.

1. Make a directory, inside your cs home directory, called jdbc.
2. Copy the following file, available from the course website, to the directory
   you just made: mysql-connector-java-3.0.6-stable-bin.jar.
3. Open the file .bashrc in your home directory with an editor such as
   emacs. (Note that files whose names begin with . are ordinarily hidden
   by default, so you may need to “show hidden files” to get to .bashrc.)
4. Add the following two lines the file .bashrc (anywhere in the file), changing ”username” to your own username:

MYSQLDRV="mysql-connector-java-3.0.6-stable-bin.jar"
export CLASSPATH="/home/username/jdbc/$MYSQLDRV:."

1. Save .bashrc.
2. Log out and log back in again, or, alternatively, type source .bashrc at a command prompt.

One other thing. You must inform your mySQL-connecting Eclipse projects
that you would like to use this driver. Do so by right-clicking the project in
question, choosing “Build Path — Add External Archives,” then navigating to
the aforementioned driver file. You will need to do this for every such Eclipse
project.

Comment: Java actually almost never uses the CLASSPATH environment variable (eg with `java -jar filename.jar` or `java -cp [list of jars] some.pacakage.ClassName` it is ignored). Advicing people to set it only clouds the issue.